# 86 it ! using 86 as a verb

Tags: american-english, slang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the term “86’d” relate to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/what-does-the-term-86d-relate-to)

I found that you can say "86 something" as a verb when we want to "cancel" something...

Is it used for everything??

For example, if I'm in a restaurant and changed my mind about one dish, is it correct to say "Hey, 86 it"?

**Note**: I'm not asking about the *meaning* of the verb *to 86 something*, but rather whether the verb can be used generally or only in specific contexts.

Comment: I've never heard that term. Is it some sort of jargon somewhere?

Comment: I live in new york, I heard it a couple of times but ignored the meaning until now.

Comment: @Hellion that question doesn't answer mine

Comment: @EdwinSoho Maybe not a direct answer, but it's **definitely** related, and related enough for this question and its answer(s) to be merged with that one, I think. Others might disagree...

Comment: Edwin, one question mark is enough to ask a question, and do not forget to capitalize the first letter in "for example ...". Yet, we have the period to end the sentences ("Hey, 86 it.")

Comment: I'd only use the term in a restaurant, or with someone who I knew was very familiar with restaurant terminology. In the latter case, I guess I could say something like "I'm 86 on cash," but that's hardly a normal use of the term.  In my experience (3 years in a kitchen) it doesn't really mean "to cancel" as much as it does "we're out of." I definitely wouldn't use the term to tell my waiter to cancel an order.

Comment: Mifepristone was once known as RU-486 (say it aloud to get the joke).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/86_%28term%29).

Speaking as someone who spent almost a decade working in restaurants and bars, I've never heard a customer use the term. It's jargon that restaurant employees would use speaking to each other.

In my experience it's used either to indicate you're refusing service to a particular customer, or that the establishment has either run out of an item or removed it from the menu. Even if you ordered a burger then changed your mind, I wouldn't tell the cook to "86 that burger". A much more likely scenario is I put your burger order in and the cook comes back and says that "86 on burgers" because they've run out of ground beef.