# Looking for a verb derived from a numeral

Tags: verbs

Somebody told me that - here or somewhere else on the internet - mention was made of a verb derived from a numeral, in the way of "they were sixty-foured". And that there was a lengthy discussion of the origin, e.g. some word sounding similar to the numeral, or the numeral being the number of a legal provision, rule, etc. The meaning of the verb may have been something like "neglect" or "leave unconsidered".
Is there a chance to find that word and the discussion about it?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [this question and its answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/what-does-the-term-86d-relate-to).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the term "86'd" relate to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14334/what-does-the-term-86d-relate-to)

Answer (score 5):

To ***86*** someone is to get rid of them.  Depending on context, it could be simply toss them out of an establishment or, in less savory situations, kill them.

> ***[Eighty-Six](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/eighty-six)***
> (also 86)
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
> *North American*
> *informal*
>
> 1. Eject or bar (someone) from a restaurant, bar, etc.
>    *‘they were accused of cheating, and eighty-sixed from their favorite casino’*
> 2. Reject, discard, or cancel.
>    *‘the passwords will be 86ed by next October’*

See also the [Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/86_(term)).

There is also the old kid's joke:

> Why is 6 afraid of 7?
>
> Because 7 8 9.

(8 = ate)